# Documentation for deducting private school tuition as medical expense

Tags: united-states, taxes

I have heard that private school (K-12) tuition can sometimes be tax-deductible as a medical expense, when recommended by a medical professional for specific needs.

[This link on Turbotax says:](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tips/college-and-education/tax-tips-when-sending-kids-to-private-or-public-schools/L8TJdgFAH)

> If your child is attending private school for special needs, however, you may be able to get a tax break on your K-12 private school tuition. To qualify, you’ll need a physician’s referral proving that your child requires access to specialized private education. And, if your child qualifies, you may also be able to deduct the cost of special tutoring or training in addition to tuition.

My question is, is there a specific format or wording required for this referral?

Comment: Hmm. What kind of medical ailment has “go to school” as the treatment? Please link to the claim that you came across, or provide more substantiation for it so that the community can check it out.

Comment: added specific quote from Turbotax's website

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies the context significantly.

Answer (score 1):

> I have heard that private school (K-12) tuition can sometimes be
> tax-deductible as a medical expense, when recommended by a medical
> professional.

In my experience it has worked slightly differently.

A public school student who has an Individualized Educational Plan (IEP) because they have a disability, but the local public schools cannot meet the requirements and the the student is sent to a private school. The public schools system then picks up the cost of the private school.

That is a very hard standard to meet. The public school will not agree easily. They will want to try other options first. You may have to appeal to other government agencies.

I have not known anybody who used a note from a doctor to get private school tuition to be tax deductible. The only ones I knew who got the tuition covered by the local government spent years getting the school to agree.

Even if they do agree it might end up being taxable income. I know that the cost of special tests were split between the parent and the school, and the parent received a 1099.